# Javascript 1-2 second delay on page load, weird styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, skrollr

I'm using Skrollr to animate & create parralax effects when scrolling the page, but there's a short lag which I guess is the Skrollr javascript/jQuery initialising.

Any ideas on how to avoid having the mess at the beginning?

The WP website in question is this one : http://hustynminepark.com

Thank You!

Comment: You'll have to provide more info on how and when you are initializing the plugin, but I would guess you are doing it in the <head> of the document, which would be the cause of your issues. If that is the case, you should move  your scripts to the end of you <body>.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I was calling it in the footer, the trick was just to set the initial CSS styling as someone said below. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, the layout of your page entirely depends on the activation of the plugin. You can solve this problem by finetuning the CSS so that the initial page corresponds exactly to what you see after activation of the plugin.
Also, don't forget to minify (concatenate / uglify) your javascript files before loading them into the browser; this will speed up the loading of the page and the activation of the plugin.
Btw, the site looks pretty cool.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answers are the best, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you have a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), you can use [jQuery to detect when your DOM in ready](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#lets-get-serious) then call `init`.

> First of all you want to include the skrollr.min.js file at the bottom of your document (right before the closing ) and then call skrollr.init(). Or you can place it inside the  if you want to, but make sure to call init() once the document has been loaded (e.g. jQuery's ready event or even window.onload).

Comment: Thanks for your help - That was all the case already, the trick was just to set the initial CSS styling as someone said below. Thanks tho!